# How do I extend a line pattern background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, patterns, texture

I have an image but on the top of the image there just isn't enough room to make it applicable for my desired application. Therefore I would like to extend the pattern that is clearly visible in the background. The pattern and image are the following:

[image: Original]

I tried using the content aware filter and this gives me the following result:

[image: Content Aware]

It just doesn't know how to handle the cross part. So I also tried the clone tool, and this looks good but looks like aliasing has occurred when looking from a greater distance:

[image: Clone Tool]

What to do to straighten the lines in the last image out or redo it completely in order to get a nice extended pattern?

Comment: I noticed that the line distance seems to vary a bit, which makes copying the lines a pain in the ass.

Comment: If possible, I'd remove the background and rebuild it from scratch. Your original image show wavy, uneven lines -- that can only really be corrected via reconstruction.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott says, you'd probably be better off removing the background and replicating it. It looks as though you could create and use a pattern which would save you some time. That way would avoid all the extraneous artifacts and you could apply any other filter with ease.